# Vue Teleport inside a shadow Dom

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

**Context:**

I have a Vue app rendered inside a shadow Dom.
There I have quite a few use-cases where I need teleports (https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html).

Note that a few use-cases are based on Primevue:
https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/autocomplete
But I can say that all of the use-cases use:
https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/src/components/portal/Portal.vue

Teleports require a valid CSS Selector:

> The to target of  expects a CSS selector string or an actual DOM node. Here, we are essentially telling Vue to "teleport this template fragment to the body tag".

**Problem**

However, with the exception of "self", it was not possible to find a CSS Selector that could drill into the shadow DOM.

I was able to teleport anywhere else but not into the shadow Dom.

**Code & My Attempts:**

```
<HTML>
  ...
  <body>
     ...
     <customComponent id="customElement">
        # shadow-root(open)
            <div id="mainElement"
            ...
              <Dialog
                  v-model:visible="showDialog"
                  appendTo="mainElement"   
              >
            ...
               <div id="teleportTarget"></div>
            ...
               <teleport
                  to="#teleportTarget"
               >
            ...
```

I also tried a solution from here:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-can-i-use-teleport-inside-a-custom-webelement/130423/2
But opposed to Vue, PrimeVue only accepts Strings. Even if using this solution I wasn't able to make it work.

```js
  async mounted() {
    const shadow = document.querySelector("#customElement")?.shadowRoot;
    await this.$nextTick();   //I tried with and without nextTick
    this.teleportTarget = shadow?.firstElementChild;
    console.log(this.teleportTarget);  //==> null
  },
```

**Question**

Is there a query selector, that can drill into the shadow Dom, that can be used for Vue Teleports.

Comment: "But opposed to Vue, PrimeVue only accepts Strings" - no, it accepts same values as teleport, this can be seen in source code, appendTo prop is just typed like that. Try to use `const shadow` after nextTick. Generally it's done this way, in case this doesn't work, please, provide a way to debug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that I run into a lifecycle Issue.
The solution was basically to "delay" the rendering of the teleport element like this:

```js
  <Dialog
    v-if="ready"
    :appendTo="teleportTarget"
  >
....
 data() {
    return {
      teleportTarget: null,
      ready: false,
    };
  },
 mounted() {
    this.teleportTarget = this.$el.parentNode.firstElementChild;
    this.ready = true;
  },
```

I found using this.$el to be the more "vue-ish" solution, but it also worked with document.